# The items in the DOM are added multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, local-storage, e-commerce

I got a problem,each time I add the element,it multiplicates itself(for example if there is 1 element in the cart,on the next click it will add 2 more,and if there are 3 elements,it will add 3 more,if 6,it will add 4 more),that's a huge problem,please help!

My js code:

```
let pList = document.getElementById("productList");

const addDrip = () => {
  let Drip, localObj, tObj;
  Drip = {
    name: "Traditional Drip",
    type: "normal",
    price: "2.00",
    imgSrc: "images/c5.png"
  };
  localObj = localStorage.getItem("Drip");

   if(!localObj) tObj = [];
   else tObj = JSON.parse(localObj);
   
  tObj.push(Drip)
  localStorage.setItem("Drip", JSON.stringify(tObj));
  
  for(let i = 0;i < tObj.length;i++){
    
    let htmlDrip = `
     <div class="productDiv">
     <p>${tObj[i].name}</p> 
     <p>${tObj[i].type}</p>
     <p>${tObj[i].price}$</p>
     <img src="${tObj[i].imgSrc}">
     </div>
     `
    document.getElementById("productList").innerHTML += htmlDrip;
  }
}
```

My html part:

```
<div class="cList">
      <img src="images/c5.png"class = "tDrip">
      <h1 class="Type">Traditional Drip</h1>
      <button id="tAdd"onclick="addDrip()">Add Traditional Drip</button>

    </div>

    <div id = productList></div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working environment where I can test this thing as it is unclear what is actually tObj holding and what is actually happening with the array.

Comment: That is because you are updating your `productList`'s `innerHTML` in your for loop. You can clear your `productList`'s `innerHTML` just before the for loop

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to loop thru the array while adding the new item.
You can first get the items from `localStorage`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cList">
    <img src="images/c5.png" class="tDrip">
    <h1 class="Type">Traditional Drip</h1>
    <button id="tAdd" onclick="addDrip()">Add Traditional Drip</button>

</div>

<div id="productList"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
const pList = document.getElementById("productList");
let localObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Drip"));

const parseItems = () => {

    if (!localObj) localObj = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < localObj.length; i++) {
        let htmlDrip = `
            <div class="productDiv">
                <p>${localObj[i].name}</p> 
                <p>${localObj[i].type}</p>
                <p>${localObj[i].price}$</p>
                <img src="${localObj[i].imgSrc}">
            </div>
            `;
        pList.innerHTML += htmlDrip;
    }
}

parseItems();


const addDrip = () => {
    let Drip;
    Drip = {
        name: "Traditional Drip",
        type: "normal",
        price: "2.00",
        imgSrc: "images/c5.png"
    };

    if (!localObj) localObj = [];
    localObj.push(Drip);
    localStorage.setItem("Drip", JSON.stringify(localObj));

    let htmlDrip = `
            <div class="productDiv">
                <p>${Drip.name}</p> 
                <p>${Drip.type}</p>
                <p>${Drip.price}$</p>
                <img src="${Drip.imgSrc}">
            </div>
            `;

    pList.innerHTML += htmlDrip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your array already has the drip update from the localstorage
Simply replace your JS code with this and it will work desired way you want.

```
let pList = document.getElementById("productList");

const addDrip = () => {
  let Drip, localObj, tObj;
  Drip = {
    name: "Traditional Drip",
    type: "normal",
    price: "2.00",
    imgSrc: "images/c5.png"
  };
  localObj = localStorage.getItem("Drip");
console.log(localObj,"Local object")
   if(!localObj) {
   tObj = [];
     tObj.push(Drip)
   }else {
   tObj = JSON.parse(localObj);
   console.log(tObj,"T object")
   }
  localStorage.setItem("Drip", JSON.stringify(tObj));
  
  for(let i = 0;i < tObj.length;i++){
    
    let htmlDrip = `
     <div class="productDiv">
     <p>${tObj[i].name}</p> 
     <p>${tObj[i].type}</p>
     <p>${tObj[i].price}$</p>
     <img src="${tObj[i].imgSrc}">
     </div>
     `
    document.getElementById("productList").innerHTML += htmlDrip;
  }
}
```

you just have to push when your array is empty. Give it a try it will work.

NOTE :  you can check the demo too. Just clear the localstorage if you refresh.https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GS7FA0970MF3

Comment: In that case,the needed part works but it pushes the element into localstorage just once,that is the new problem

Comment: I can see each and every time button is clicked localstorage is updated with another drip.What is the issue in this.?